# Apriori Algorithm - Mining association rules in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, data-mining, apriori

Scan the transactions to find L1
For ( k = 2; Lk-1 !empty; k++) {
Generate Ck from Lk-1
Count the occurences of itemsets in Ck
Find Lk

L1: set of all frequent 1-itemsets with counts no less than the support
Ck: set of candidates k-itemsets
Lk: subset of Ck with counts no less than the support

Transactions (dataset.txt)

```
A, B, E   
B, D   
B, C  
A, B, D   
A, C   
B, C   
A, C   
A, B, C, E  
A, B, C   
F
```

Support(min) = 20%

Our association rule data mining task has multiple parameters and stages:

1. Generate candidates, then scan and count, then check min support
   Here it's generating C till C3 however C2 is not counting and C3 giving the wrong value.

C3 should be

```
{A, B, C}  
{A, B, D}  
{A, B, E}  
{A, C, D}  
{A, C, E}  
{A, D, E}  
{B, C, D}  
{B, C, E}  
{B, D, E}  
{C, D, E}
```

However we're getting

```
A B C 
C A D 
A E E
```

This is a wrong result.
So the first error is C2 and C3 are not counting and also C3 is giving the wrong result.

My code is as follows:

**Main.java**

```
package apriori;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class Main {
    public static int minSup = 2;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    FileWriter summary= new FileWriter("Summary.txt");
    String Freqitems = "Frequent.txt";
    String Infreqitems = "Infrequent.txt";
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    do{
        CandidateGen.CandGen();
        CandidateGen.CandGen();
        CandidateGen.CandGen();

    }while(SupportCounter.itemsize > 0);

//  WRITING SUMMARY FILE        
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        LineNumberReader  Frelnr = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(Freqitems));
        LineNumberReader  Infrelnr = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(Infreqitems));
        Frelnr.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE);
        Infrelnr.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE);
        long totalTime = (endTime - startTime);
        summary.write("MinSup = "+minSup+System.getProperty("line.separator" )+
                        "Total T(C): "+CandidateGen.gettime()+" Nano seconds"+System.getProperty("line.separator" )+
                        "Total T(L): "+SupportCounter.gettime()+" Nano seconds"+System.getProperty("line.separator" )+
                        "Total Time of Execution = "+totalTime+" nano seconds"+System.getProperty("line.separator" )+
                        "Frequent itemsets: "+(Frelnr.getLineNumber() - 1)+System.getProperty("line.separator")+
                        "Infrequent itemsets: "+(Infrelnr.getLineNumber() - 1)+System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        summary.close();
        Frelnr.close();
        Infrelnr.close();
    }
}
```

**SupportCounter.java**

```
package apriori;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SupportCounter{
    static long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    static int callcount = 0;
    static int itemsize=0;
    public static void SupCoun()
    {
    //  HashMap map = new HashMap(); 
    //  String dataset = "dataset.txt";//determines name of file
        try {
            callcount = callcount +1;

            if(callcount ==1){

                HashMap map = new HashMap(); 
            String dataset = "Dataset.txt";//determines name of file
        //  callcount = callcount +1;
            FileWriter Lk = new FileWriter("L"+callcount+".txt");
            Scanner list = new Scanner(new File(dataset));


            while (list.hasNext()) {

                String word = list.next();
                if (!list.hasNext()){
                    Lk.write("Time of Execution : "+ gettime()+" nano seconds"+System.getProperty("line.separator" ));
                }
                if(map.containsKey(word)) {
                    //itemsize=1;
                  Integer count = (Integer)map.get(word);
                  map.put(word, new Integer(count.intValue() + 1));
                } else {
                   map.put(word, new Integer(1));
                }
              }
            ArrayList arraylist = new ArrayList(map.keySet());
            Collections.sort(arraylist);
            for (int i = 0; i < arraylist.size(); i++) {
              String key = (String)arraylist.get(i);
              Integer count = (Integer)map.get(key);
            if( count >= Main.minSup)
                    {
                    Lk.write(key + " : " + count + System.getProperty( "line.separator" ));
                    }
                }      
            list.close();
            Lk.close();
            }//call count = 1 if end

            else if(callcount > 1){ // Write Lk
                countfre(callcount);

            }//else-if end
        } // Try END

        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }//SupCoun END

private static void countfre(int filenumber) throws IOException{

        ArrayList<String> ckwords = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> dbwords = new ArrayList<String>();
        FileWriter Lk = new FileWriter("L"+filenumber+".txt");
        File ck = new File("C"+filenumber+".txt");
        Scanner ckscan = new Scanner(ck);//.useDelimiter(":");

         File dataset = new File("Dataset.txt");
         Scanner dbscan = new Scanner(dataset).useDelimiter("\n");

         int j1,i1 =0;
         if(ckscan.hasNext())
         {
         ckscan.nextLine();
         }
         Lk.write("Time of Execution : "+ gettime()+" nano seconds"+System.getProperty("line.separator" ));
         while(dbscan.hasNext())
         {

             String wrd = dbscan.nextLine();
             dbwords.add(wrd);
         }
         while(ckscan.hasNext())
         {
             String wrd2 = ckscan.nextLine();
             ckwords.add(wrd2);
         }
         int counter =0;
         ckscan = new Scanner(ck);//.useDelimiter(":");
         if(ckscan.hasNext())
         ckscan.nextLine();
         while(ckscan.hasNext())
         {
             dbscan = new Scanner(dataset).useDelimiter("\n");
             String wrd2 = ckscan.nextLine();
             ckwords.add(wrd2);

             for(j1=0;j1<dbwords.size();j1++){
                 if(dbwords.get(j1).contains(wrd2)){
                     counter++;
                 }
             }

             if(counter >= Main.minSup){

             Lk.write(wrd2+" : "+counter+ System.getProperty( "line.separator" ));
             }
            // System.out.println(wrd2+"--"+counter);
       // System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------");
         }
         Lk.close();         
      }




//////////////END TIMER
public static long gettime()
    {
        long endTime   = System.nanoTime();
        long totalTime = (long) ((endTime - startTime));
        return(totalTime);
    }
}
```

**CandidateGen.java**

```
package apriori;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CandidateGen {
    static long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    static int callcount = 0;

public static void CandGen()
    {
        //HashMap map = new HashMap(); 
        try {
            String dataset = "dataset.txt";//determines name of file
            callcount = callcount +1;

            if(callcount == 1)
            {
            HashMap map = new HashMap();
            FileWriter Ck = new FileWriter("C"+callcount+".txt");
            FileWriter Infeq = new FileWriter("Infrequent.txt");
            FileWriter Feq = new FileWriter("Frequent.txt");

            Scanner list = new Scanner(new File(dataset));
            while (list.hasNext()) {

                String word = list.next();
                if (!list.hasNext()){
                    Feq.write("Time of execution : "+gettime()+" nano seconds"+System.getProperty("line.separator" ));
                    Infeq.write("Time of execution : "+gettime()+" nano seconds"+ System.getProperty("line.separator" ));
                    Ck.write("Time of execution : "+gettime()+" nano seconds"+ System.getProperty("line.separator" ));
                }               
                if(map.containsKey(word)) {
                  Integer count = (Integer)map.get(word);
                  map.put(word, new Integer(count.intValue() + 1));
                } else {
                   map.put(word, new Integer(1));
                }
              }
            ArrayList arraylist = new ArrayList(map.keySet());
            Collections.sort(arraylist);
            for (int i = 0; i < arraylist.size(); i++) {
              String key = (String)arraylist.get(i);
              Integer count = (Integer)map.get(key);

            if( count < Main.minSup)
            {
                Infeq.write(key  + System.getProperty( "line.separator" ));
            }
            else{
                Feq.write(key + System.getProperty( "line.separator" ));
                }
            Ck.write(key +" : "+count+System.getProperty( "line.separator" ));
               }
            //System.out.println("Frequent and Infrequent items separated to frequent.txt , infrequent.txt ");
            list.close();
            Infeq.close();
            Feq.close();
            Ck.close();
            SupportCounter.SupCoun();
        } 
        /// 2-itemset
            else if(callcount == 2){ // Write Ck
                String Lk = "L"+(callcount-1)+".txt";
                FileWriter Ck = new FileWriter("C"+callcount+".txt");
                HashMap map = new HashMap();
                Scanner list = new Scanner(new File(Lk));
                list.nextLine();

                while (list.hasNext()) {
                String word = list.next();

                if(map.containsKey(word)) {
                      Integer count = (Integer)map.get(word);

                      map.put(word, new Integer(count.intValue() + 1));
                    } else {
                       map.put(word, new Integer(1));
                    }
                list.nextLine();
                  }//while 

                ArrayList arraylist = new ArrayList(map.keySet());
                Collections.sort(arraylist);

                Ck.write("Time of execution : "+gettime()+" nano seconds"+ System.getProperty("line.separator" ));

                for (int i = 0; i < arraylist.size(); i++) {

                    for (int j = i+1; j < arraylist.size(); j++) {

                      String key = (String)arraylist.get(i);
                      String key2 = (String)arraylist.get(j);
                      Ck.write(key + " " + key2 + System.getProperty( "line.separator" ));
                   // System.out.println(key + "," + key2 );
                    }
                }
                Ck.close();
                countfre(callcount);
                SupportCounter.SupCoun();
            }//else-if end

    /// 3-itemset
            else if(callcount >2){
            String Lk = "L"+(callcount-1)+".txt";
            FileWriter Ck = new FileWriter("C"+callcount+".txt");
            Scanner list = new Scanner(new File(Lk));
            Scanner list2 = new Scanner(new File(Lk));
            list.nextLine();
            int c=0;
            ArrayList arraylist= new ArrayList();
            ArrayList arraylist2= new ArrayList();
            //HashMap map = new HashMap();

            while(list.hasNext())
            {
                String word = list.next();
                c++;
                //System.out.println(word);
                if(word.contains(":"))
                {
                    list.nextLine();
                    c=0;
                    continue;
                }
                else if(c == callcount)
                {
                    if(list.hasNext())
                    {

                    list.nextLine();
                    continue;
                    }
                    else
                        break;
                }
                //System.out.println(word);
                arraylist.add(word);
                }

            list2.nextLine();
            list2.nextLine();
            while(list2.hasNext())
            {
                String word = list2.next();
                c++;
                //System.out.println(word);
                if(word.contains(":"))
                {
                    list2.nextLine();
                    c=0;
                    continue;
                }
                else if(c == callcount)
                {
                    if(list2.hasNext())
                    {

                    list2.nextLine();
                    continue;
                    }
                    else
                        break;
                }
                //System.out.println(word);
                arraylist2.add(word);

            }
            int el = 0;
            String set3,set4;
            ArrayList arraylist3= new ArrayList();
            //Scanner scanarray = new Scanner((Readable) arraylist2);
            for(int i=0;i<arraylist.size();i++)
            {

                c++;
                set3 = (String) arraylist.get(i);
                for(int j=0;j<(arraylist2.size());j++)
                {

                    set4 = (String)arraylist2.get(j);
                    if(set3.contains(set4))
                        {
                            //System.out.println(i+" "+j);
                            i++;
                            //System.out.println(i+" "+j);
                            //j++;
                            //System.out.println(i-1+" "+i+" "+(j+1)+"-");
                            String w = (String)arraylist.get(i-1);
                            String w2 = (String) arraylist.get(i);
                            //j++;
                            String w3 = (String) arraylist2.get(j+1);
                            System.out.println(w +" "+w2+" "+w3);
                            Ck.write(w+" "+w2+" "+w3+System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                            arraylist3.add(w);
                            arraylist3.add(w2);
                            arraylist3.add(w3);
                            el++;

                            //System.out.println(el);
                        }
                    i=i+1;
                    //j=j+2;
                    }
                //  j=j=0;
                }
            for(int i=0;i<el;i++)
            {
            //  System.out.println(arraylist3.get(i));
            }
            //}
            Ck.close();

            countfre(callcount);

        }//else-if end

    }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

private static void countfre(int filenumber) throws IOException{

    ArrayList<String> ckwords = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> dbwords = new ArrayList<String>();

    File ck = new File("C2.txt");
     Scanner ckscan = new Scanner(ck);//.useDelimiter(":");

     File dataset = new File("dataset.txt");
     Scanner dbscan = new Scanner(dataset).useDelimiter("\n");

     int j1,i1 =0;
     ckscan.nextLine();
     while(dbscan.hasNext())
     {
         String wrd = dbscan.nextLine();
         dbwords.add(wrd);
     }
     while(ckscan.hasNext())
     {
         String wrd2 = ckscan.nextLine();
         ckwords.add(wrd2);
     }
     int counter =0;
     ckscan = new Scanner(ck);//.useDelimiter(":");
     ckscan.nextLine();
     while(ckscan.hasNext())
     {
         dbscan = new Scanner(dataset).useDelimiter("\n");
         String wrd2 = ckscan.nextLine();
         ckwords.add(wrd2);
         for(j1=0;j1<dbwords.size();j1++){
             if(dbwords.get(j1).contains(wrd2)){
                 counter++;
             }

     }
 //      System.out.println(wrd2+"--"+counter);
  //  System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------");
     }
  }




    // END of TIMER
    public static   double gettime()
    {
        long endTime   = System.nanoTime();
        double totalTime = (double) ((endTime - startTime));
        return (double) (totalTime);
    }
}
```

2. Mining Rules from frequent itemsets
   The code is not supporting Mining Rules example

   Rule       Confidence       Support
   A => B      66%              40%
   A => C      66%              40%
   A => E      33%              20%
   B => C      57%              40%
   B => D      29%              20%
   B => E      29%              20%

Any critique is much appreciated. Thank you in advanced

Comment: This is very *long* and hard to follow code. Don't expect us to read all of it. Narrow it down, and simplify the code - that helps finding errors.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse it's not easy to narrow down the code, to better understand the case I had to post the full code if you're familiar with Apriori and can help even for a cost please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: There are different websites for for-hire jobs.  As you can tell by the number of answers you have received, nobody is going to read and debug a code this long here.